# Get computers list from certain OU in active directory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using the powershell command below to get a list of computers that havent been logged into in the past 60 days. This is returning all OU computers. Is it possible to change the line below to return from a certain OU?

```
Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate -Filter {lastLogonDate -lt $then} | FT Name,lastLogonDate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the online [help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852328) page try using -SearchBase filter

```
C:\PS>Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=*laptop*)" -SearchBase "CN=Computers,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com"
```